# How to assort the cell in Karnaugh map

Tags: c++, boolean-logic, logical-operators

i have some problem in categorization of karnaugh map,i don't know how define Various cases of karnaugh table,

if i use consecutive " if " and " else " statement,i think it is very low-level programming,i want some algorithm that will be known assortment itself,or using less "if" and " else" statement
here i have some categorization example of Karnaugh map:

[image]

my program have to know that this two "1"'s is in one category ,and the will be categorized both
how can i Inculcate this to my program,how can i implement this categorization 
this is my code for two variable karnaugh map:

```
int num_var;        // stores the number of variables entered by user
int squ_4[4];       // variable used for a 1-D array for the 4 square Karnaugh map
int a,b,c;          // variables for entering and checking values in Karnaugh map squares
char var_name[10];  // character string array

strcpy(var_name,"ABCDRSXYZ");   // character string for variable name

printf("\nThis program works out a Boolean function for a 2,3 and 4 variable Karnaugh map.\n\n");

cout << "Enter number of Karnaugh map variables (2,3 or 4) required: ";
cin >> num_var;
do
{
    if(num_var>4)
    {
        printf("\n Sorry, you have chosen too many variables \n");
        printf("\n Please enter 2,3 or 4 variables: ");
        cin >> num_var;
    }
    if(num_var<2)
    {
        printf("\n Sorry, not enough variables chosen \n");
        printf("\n Please enter 2,3 or 4 variables: ");
        cin >> num_var;
    }
}while(num_var>4 || num_var<2);

do
{
    printf("\nVariables are: %c %c \n",var_name[4],var_name[5]);    // output variable names

    printf("\n Please enter value in Karnaugh map square and press RETURN \n")

    for(a=0;a<4;a++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter 1 or 0 into square %d: ",a);
        cin >> squ_4[a];    // store value into array

        while(squ_4[a]!=0 && squ_4[a]!=1)
        {
            printf("\n Value entered in Karnaugh map square %d, was not 1 or 0 \n",a);
            printf("\nPlease enter 1 or 0 into square %d: ",a);
            cin >> squ_4[a];
        }
    }
    printf("\nYour Karnaugh map is: \n\n\t\t     %c'%c \n\t\t   %c'%d %d\n\t\t   %c %d %d \n",var_name[5],var_name[5],var_name[4],squ_4[0],squ_4[1],var_name[4],squ_4[2],squ_4[3]);


    if(squ_4[0]==0 && squ_4[1]==0 && squ_4[2]==0 && squ_4[3]==0)
    {
        printf("\nThere is no function from the Karnaugh map\n\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("\nThe Boolean function is: \n\n ");

    if(squ_4[0]==1)
    {
        printf("%c'%c' ",var_name[4],var_name[5]);
        if(squ_4[1]==1 || squ_4[2]==1 || squ_4[3]==1)
        {
            printf("+ ");
        }
    }
    if(squ_4[1]==1)
    {
        printf("%c'%c ",var_name[4],var_name[5]);
        if(squ_4[2]==1 || squ_4[3]==1)
        {
            printf("+ ");
        }
    }
    if(squ_4[2]==1)
    {
        printf("%c%c' ",var_name[4],var_name[5]);
        if(squ_4[3]==1)
        {
            printf("+ ");
        }
    }
    if(squ_4[3]==1)
    {
        printf("%c%c ",var_name[4],var_name[5]);
    }

    cout << "\n\n\n\n";
}while(num_var==2);
```

Comment: is there any another way to implement some thing like this? :\

Answer (score 1):

store their answers in  some variable  and compare the result by using loops .